# If user is coming from domain testx.com, rewrite url to mydomain.com/testx

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, url-rewriting, web-config

I have an ASP.Net website, but several domain names are pointing to the same website.
so for example lets say i have following domains

```
www.myMainDomain.com
www.mySite1.com
www.mySite2.com
```

I have 1 actual website with all the pages and subpages i want to have.

```
www.myMainDomain.com

www.myMainDomain.com/site1
www.myMainDomain.com/site1/products

www.myMainDomain.com/site2
www.myMainDomain.com/site2/products
...
```

So i would like to have a rewrite rule in my web.config
so that if the user is coming from the [www.myMainDomain.com](http://www.myMainDomain.com), it is just the normal site as it is existing
but if they are coming from [www.mySite1.com](http://www.mySite1.com), the rewrite rule should kind of take them to [www.myMainDomain.com/site1](http://www.myMainDomain.com/site1), and if they go to a subpage, like products, it is always rewritten so like this

```
www.mySite1.com            -> www.myMainDomain.com/site1
www.mySite1.com/products   -> www.myMainDomain.com/site1/products
```

I have something like that, but this is not working, and it is actually causing a 500 Error

```
<system.webServer>
  <rewrite xdt:Transform="Insert">
    <rules>
      <rule name="Root Hit Redirect" stopProcessing="true">
        <match url="^$" />
        <action type="Redirect" url="/site1/{R:1}" appendQueryString="true" />
      </rule>
    </rules>
  </rewrite>
</system.webServer>
```

What could be a correct solution?

Comment: When you say "is coming from" - do you mean the user browser sets a Referer of x, or do you mean their IP address looks up to be belonging to domain x?

Comment: i mean the user is browsing in chrome fe to https://www.mySite1.com

Answer (score 0):

I think you could use the inverse of standard canonicalhostname redirect with some changes:

```
<rule name="CanonicalHostNameRule_Mod" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url="(.*)" />
    <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll" trackAllCaptures="false">
        <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^www\.mySite1\.com$" />
    </conditions>
    <action type="Redirect" url="http://www.myMainDomain.com/site1/{R:1}" />
</rule>
```

In this way you have to make a rule for each secondary domain.